# How do I access the metroid easter egg in Donkey Kong Country: Tropical Freeze?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze

What are the steps needed to access the Metroid easter egg in Donkey Kong Country: Tropical Freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this demo video that answers the question:

https://kotaku.com/four-years-later-players-found-a-metroid-hidden-in-don-1828087121

**Edit:**

Here are the steps to encounter the metroid (from the article):

"The metroid appears in level 4-3, Amiss Abyss, in the Sea Breeze Cove world, but it’s not in any secret location. Instead, it will only appear if you backtrack to an earlier part of the level.

Right after hitting the halfway point, there’s a section of the level filled with glowing jellyfish in the background and a mechanism Donkey Kong has to trigger in order to clear a path forward through some electrical seaweed. After passing through this part and getting outside the following tunnel, you can then swim backwards to the mechanism again by taking damage and passing through the sea weed while invincible. Once you’re back on the other side, wait a few moments, and eventually you’ll see a metroid swimming from the bottom of the screen up toward the top."

Comment: It's a good idea to quote the recent parts of the link and/or summarize the video in the case that the link was to go down for any reason

Comment: Added the description